# JQuery UI Dialog - unwanted space below dialog box

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm working on a simple tic-tac-toe application and building it in CodePen. When the user loses or forces a draw (designed to be unbeatable), a jquery UI dialog box pops up informing the user of said result. Issue I'm having, is that when this happens, a large empty space appears causing a scroll bar to appear at the right of the page. This is a small detail - but I'd like to fix. I cannot put `overflow: hidden` on the body because then users won't be able to scroll on small screens or in resized browser windows. I've already tried the following to no avail:

- adjusting position of dialog to very top of screen
- putting `overflow: hidden` rule just on `.ui-dialog`
- adjusting the height of the dialog box
- adjusting the `margin-bottom` of `.ui-dialog`
- messing with other dialog options to see if they were the cause

Some of these seemed far-fetched but I wanted to try everything I could think of before coming here. Research has turned nothing up either. I'm running Chrome and the pen in question can be found here: http://codepen.io/no_stack_dub_sack/pen/YGNRxO.

Any help on this would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Again, this is a small detail, but since the app fits all on one page without scroll on most screens, I'd like to keep it looking as clean as possible.

Here's the code:

```
// DIALOG BOXES

      $('body').append('<div id="draw" class="gameOver"><p>It\'s a Draw!</p></div>');
      $('body').append('<div id="loser" class="gameOver"><p>You Lose!</p></div>');
      $('.gameOver').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height: 120,
        dialogClass: 'no-close',
        buttons: {
          'Play Again?': function() {
            $('.gameOver').dialog('close');
            setNewGame();
          }
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in the dialog creation process, the position is set to relative on your dialog, which causes the height of your game to calculate the dialog, which gives the empty gap. You can simply set ui-dialog position to absolute in the css, and it'll solve the problem:

```
.ui-dialog {
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px 5px;
  background: #04A777;
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: none;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EgmoGZ

Comment: Wow, so simple - it worked, and much appreciated! It was frustrating me to no end. It seems like a tiny thing, but I think the effect is much cleaner this way. Hope someone else will come across the same issue and find this useful. Thanks again!